# .NET Core - Regular Expressions - Accessing Captures Within A Matched Line Of Text

Tags: regex, .net-core

I am trying to learn regular expressions with .net core. In particular I am trying to use them to parse a list of embedded resources in an assembly as shown below.

**Regular Expression Pattern**

`^([\w\._])*((?<create>\.Postgres.Create\.)|(?<drop>\.Postgres.Drop\.)([\w\._]))*$`

**Sample text generated from list of embedded resources**

```
Mynamespace.Postgresql.Create.select_course_units.sql
Mynamespace.Postgresql.Drop.drop_select_course_units.sql
Mynamespace.Postgresql.Create.select_units.sql
Mynamespace.Postgresql.Drop.drop_select_units.sql
...
```

The regular expression has two named capture groups for *Postgres.Create* and *Postgres.Drop* captures, respectivley. My regular expression finds both matches but there is nothing stored in the captures for create or drop groups. Is it possible to get it to store the captures so that it can be determined whether a match contains create or drop?

```cs
public void ReadCreateStoredProcedures()
{
    const string pattern = @"^([\w\._])*((?<create>\.Postgres.Create\.)|(?<drop>\.Postgres.Drop\.)([\w\._]))*$";  
    Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    string[] resNames = typeof(CourseContext).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    string text = string.Join("\n",resNames);

    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Matched{match.Value}");
        GroupCollection col = match.Groups;

        int lC = col["create"].Length;
        int lD = col["drop"].Length;

        Console.WriteLine($"Total Create Captures : {lC}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Drop Captures : {lD}");

        foreach(var capture in col["create"].Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Create Capture :: {@capture}");
        }
        foreach (var capture in col["drop"].Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drop Capture :: {@capture}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you don't get the values in the named capturing groups because this part at the beginning `([\w\._])*` will first match all the way until the end of the string.

You do get 1 capture group (not the named capture group) with a single char which would be the last char of the string as when repeating a captured group, the group will contain the value of the last iteration.

What follows is an optional part `((?<create>\.Postgres.Create\.))*$`. As it is optional, the pattern can assert the following end of the string and the named capture group does not contain a value.

**Note** that `\w` also matches an underscore and you don't have to escape the dot in the character class

---

If you want to capture both values starting from `Postgresql`, you could use the 2 capturing group like this for example:

```
^\w+\.(?:(?<create>Postgresql\.Create(?:\.\w+)+)|(?<drop>Postgresql\.Drop(?:\.\w+)+))$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+\.` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<create>` Named group `create`

    - `Postgresql\.Create(?:\.\w+)+ Match Postgresql.Create and repeat matching a`.` and 1+ word chars
  - `)` Close group
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<drop>` Named group `drop`

    - `Postgresql\.Drop(?:\.\w+)+` Same as above for Postgresql.Drop
  - `)` Named group `drop`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cw%2b%5c.%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ccreate%3ePostgresql%5c.Create%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b%29%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cdrop%3ePostgresql%5c.Drop%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b%29%2b%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=Mynamespace.Postgresql.Create.select_course_units.sql%0d%0aMynamespace.Postgresql.Drop.drop_select_course_units.sql%0d%0aMynamespace.Postgresql.Create.select_units.sql%0d%0aMynamespace.Postgresql.Drop.drop_select_units.sql&o=m) (Click on the `Table` tab)

Comment: Hi and many thanks, greatly appreciated with a clear explanation :) I had to modify to ```^(?:\w+\.)+(?:(?<create>Postgresql\.Create(?:\.\w+)+)|(?<drop>Postgresql\.Drop(?:\.\w+)+))\n?$``` to account for some embedded namespaces such as ```Courses.Infrastructure.StoredProcedures.Postgresql.Create.select_course_units.sql``` After doing this I am getting a match with the dollar symboll prepended, e.g. ```$Courses.Infrastructure.StoredProcedures.Postgresql.Create.select_course_units.sql```. Think it is something with \n character. I am joining with new lines of \n but still getting $ prepended.

Comment: You are welcome. That pattern by itself does not match that string starting with a dollar sign. https://regex101.com/r/BlSxGC/1 Are you sure that the `$` character does not come from another part?

Comment: It is so close, almost there.... I can see the captures now, appreciated...I think the latest pattern ( ```^(?:\w+\.)+(?:(?<create>Postgresql\.Create(?:\.\w+)+)|(?<drop>Postgresql\.Drop(?:\.\w+)+))\n?$``` ) is inserting the $ character from the end of line delimiter ($) somehow? Each namespace is separated with a \n character, so I replaced the trailing \r in the original pattern....The $ appears irrespective of \n or \r....

Comment: Sorted many thanks again, appreciated :) I had mistakingly included a $ character in a Console.WriteLine statement. Accepting your answer :)